# Perform a find between a matrix and a vector and concatenate results - MATLAB

Tags: vectorization, matlab

I have a 3D array

```
 a = meshgrid(2500:1000:25000,2500:1000:25000,2500:1000:25000);
```

Usually I use a loop to execute the following logic

```
k =[];
for b = 0.01:0.01:0.2
    c = find(a <= b.*0.3 & a <= b.*0.5);
    if(~isempty(c))
        for i=1:length(c)
            k = vertcat(k,a(c(i)));
        end
    end
end
```

How do I remove the loop? And perform the action above with one line

Of course

```
b = [0.01:0.01:0.2];
c=find(a<b*.8)
```

is not possible

Comment: Please add what your `output` matrix will be...

Comment: Are you sure that loop does what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry i had major flaws

Comment: Wow where did that old question go!? :)

Comment: I was trying to make my question simpler, but bsxfun does not work with my actual vectors.

Comment: So let me confirm - Is `a` a 3D array and `b` a row vector in *your actual case*?

Comment: Yes the code above matches my code, except you either use b in the loop or you define it. So in my case i use it in the loop.

Comment: If b is positive, then `a <= b.*0.3 & a <= b.*0.5` wouldn't always be equivalent to `a <= b.*0.3`?

Comment: Correct, but this is based on arbitrary tests. So i do test for example -0.3.

Comment: Please 1) edit your title to make more sense in accordance with the body of the question, 2) Remove the starting `b` array 3) format code properly. Appreciate the help!

Comment: What should the title be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bsxfun` based approach to create a mask for the `find`s and using it to index into a replicated version of input array, `a` to have the desired output -

```
vals = repmat(a,[1 1 1 numel(b)]); %// replicated version of input array
mask = bsxfun(@le,a,permute(b*0.3,[1 4 3 2])) & ...
    bsxfun(@le,a,permute(b*0.5,[1 4 3 2])); %// mask created
k = vals(mask); %// desired output in k
```

Please note that you would be needed to change the function handle used with `bsxfun` according to the condition you would be using.

Comment: I was trying to make my question simpler, but bsxfun does not work with my actual vectors.

Comment: @user2333346 Check out the edit part?  Remember to feed the 3D array as `a` and the row vector as `b` into the edited code.

Comment: But isn't this for only one side of the logic (i.e. <= b.*0.3 ) how  do i include the & (i.e. a <= b.*0.3 & a <= b.*0.5)

Comment: @user2333346 Use this - `mask = bsxfun(@le,a,permute(b*0.3,[1 4 3 2])) & bsxfun(@le,a,permute(b*0.5,[1 4 3 2]));` instead.

Comment: I would have given 100 thumbs up, but they only allow one.

Comment: @user2333346 haha that's okay! It's really the helpful feedback that matters the most really and I am sensing some good feedback here! :)

Comment: @user2333346 So, just curious on how well this solution performs against your loopy code in your actual case in terms of runtimes I mean?

Comment: PERFECT, i wouldn't have excepted if it didn't.

Comment: Example A minor loop from 6sec to almost nothing.

Comment: @user2333346 Now that sounds awesome! Good job and good luck!!